# Git revert pushed commit

Tags: git, github, git-merge

I made a commit on git and pushed it from master branch.

But then I realised few changes are remaining.
So I created a new branch on my local committed, pushed and merged previous and remaining changes altogether from the new branch.

Now when I checkout to master branch it give's  the following error

```
You have unmerged paths.
```

I think the issue is with commit which I want to delete now.
So how can I delete the last commit which I did from master branch.

Comment: This is my favourite 'argh, I wish I hadn't done that' resource for git: [http://sethrobertson.github.io/GitFixUm/fixup.html](http://sethrobertson.github.io/GitFixUm/fixup.html)

Comment: can you please post the full output of teh commit or status?

Answer (score 1):

The error means that you having conflicts due to your merge,
you cant checkout new branch until you discard or resolve them.

More info can be found here:
https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-from-the-command-line/

---

#### Step to try

1. Fix the conflicts
2. Add all your files using `git add . -A`
3. Commit your changes
4. checkout the `master` branch

Comment: Okay. I resolved the issue by deleting the master branch from local and recreated it again.

Comment: Cool, so can you be kind enough to accept the answer and vote for it. Thank you